# MiddlewareInServerlessTargetError: Next.js Middleware is not supported in the deprecated target

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

Currently I have project which was running on aws amplify. On the local side I can build successfully and start it but. After implemented the middleware and try to deploy with amplify. It caused this error. Couldn't find any solution,

> Build error occurred
> MiddlewareInServerlessTargetError: Next.js Middleware is not supported in the deprecated  target.
> Please remove `target: "" from your next.config.js to use Middleware.

**next.config.js**

[image]

**middleware.ts**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amplify doesn't support anything above Next 11

See the conversation here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41932

Answer (score 0):

You're right, after detailed research I found a title which includes new features on amplify.

Here,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#ssr-Amplify-support